# Why do one have to be root to acces gpio?

Tags: gpio, driver, root

I have long wondered about this.
I mean there are a lot of low level stuff that a user can get access to.
If a driver exports gpio to /dev/gpio and that file is writable by group gpio how would that be any different from group callout being able to use the serial port?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK there is no `/dev/gpio` driver in Linux. There is, however, `/sys/class/gpio` directory, which makes very similar case. But that's only one way to interface with GPIO on RaspberryPi. The other one is to bypass Linux kernel drivers and talk to memory mapped hardware registers directly. Some libraries/applications can only use one of this methods while others can be configured to use either of them. Let's consider both cases.

### Linux driver

As already mentioned, Linux driver exports `/sys/class/gpio` directory where you can find couple of files and sub directories that you can use to control `GPIO`. By default the directory and it's content are all owned by `root user` and `root group` and only root can write to them. This default setting is reasonable since if you have direct access to GPIO pins, you are able to directly interface with external hardware connected to them. In Linux, the usual way to talk to hardware is using kernel provided drivers instead. So it could be a security hole if someone could use GPIO pins directly (for example before the driver is loaded). Also it is sometimes possible to break the system when directly using GPIO pins - on RaspberryPi it is possible to disconnect Ethernet card this way, for example.

That being said, there is nothing that stops you from configuring you system so that this directory is writable by some trusted users. You can also pre-export some individual GPIO pins and allow them to be writable by any user. It's just not enabled by default because of the reasons I already explained.

### Directly interfacing hardware registers

You can also use GPIO using it's hardware registers (this is what kernel driver is doing for you) which are mapped into memory. In order to do this, you need raw access to whole RaspberryPi's memory. There is a driver for that in Linux - it exposes the memory by `/dev/mem` file. If you have access to this file, you have access to whole memory, including every memory mapped peripheral in your system. It is also only available for root by default since it is **very** insecure to give access to the memory to any nontrusted user. Having access to the memory means you can access to all kernel data structures so one can easily bypass any system security.

Again, you can configure your system to allow other users to access this file but it is much more insecure than giving access to the `/sys/class/gpio` directory.

Comment: So basically if someone wrote a character driver and exported character device files to /dev/pin1 and so or maybe /dev/spi you could safely let users get acces to those files?

Comment: @evading: There is no need to write such driver since `/sys/class/gpio` is there exactly for that reason. Whether it is secure or not, depends on what kind of security are you talking about. It is safe if there is nothing that could somehow damage the system connected to this pin. So in most situations, there is no danger in doing this.

Comment: Ok, then I see. I would think that most hobbyists should have that file accessible by unprivileged users since I would be much more hesitant to run homebrewn software as root during testing than to have whoever turn my led off. But maybe that's just me =)
But off cause that would depend on what your controlling with your GPIO and who else has access to the system.